# Json_object in Oracle returns ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: json, oracle

I am trying to convert Oracle table data into JSON files. I have three databases and the below code gives output as JSON file in one DB but the other two databases throw `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error`.

Syntactically it is correct, as it gave output in one DB. Don't understand what is going wrong. 
This is in Oracle DB, How do I find out which version of Oracle is installed in those DB's and if they are 12.2 and above, Is there a way to fix this issue? All I want is to convert the output of a select statement to a json file. Thanks in advance

code:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT ( 'empid' value eid , 'name' value ename , 'add' value eaddr ) 
FROM abc.emp
```

---

Comment: Perhaps the database where this works is version 12.2 or higher, and the other two databases are version 12.1 or earlier?

Comment: I think @mathguy is correct: JSON_OBJECT() was new to [Oracle 12c R2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Changes-in-This-Release-for-Oracle-Database-SQL-Language-Reference.html#GUID-F7977934-38CE-45FB-AB55-7F67E7285D0C)

Comment: In which db is it giving output?

Comment: This is in Oracle DB, How do I find out which version of Oracle is installed in those DB's and if they are 12.2 and above, Is there a way to fix this issue? All I want is to convert the output of a select statement to json file. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15):

JSON_Object is available from Oracle version  12.2 .

Run the query Select * from v$version to check your oracle version