# Why am i getting error with this JSON_OBJECT usage

Tags: sql, arrays, json, oracle

I am trying to generate a JSON output from a SQL Query. I read in one of the threads on this site, the following should return a JSON file:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(*) FROM hr.employees ;
```

However, I get the following error:

> ORA-00936: missing expression
>   00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
>
> *Cause: 
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 12 Column: 20

I am running Oracle 12.c 12.1.0.2.0-64bit version.

Comment: Sample data from the `employees` table along with the expected output would be really helpful here.

Comment: your code looks about right (see https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_HT1U9Z9IZB03YZOD77B6D5411.html) but it depends on the content of the table, of course

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json\_object in Oracle returns ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52195918/json-object-in-oracle-returns-ora-00907-missing-right-parenthesis)

Comment: json_object requires oracle 12.2, see linked question

Answer (score 0):

You can not use JSON_OBJECT(*) to query JSON OBJECT from database. Here is the example of `JSON_OBJECT`.

Evaluates a (possibly empty) list of key/value pairs and returns a JSON object containing those pairs. An error occurs if any key name is NULL or the number of arguments is odd.

```
mysql> SELECT JSON_OBJECT('id', 87, 'name', 'carrot');
+-----------------------------------------+
| JSON_OBJECT('id', 87, 'name', 'carrot') |
+-----------------------------------------+
| {"id": 87, "name": "carrot"}            |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: And how exactly does a MySQL solution help with an Oracle question?